# OpenCV: How do I pass my image to another method?

Tags: python, opencv, object, variables, initialization

I am trying to use OpenCV to capture an image. I then want this image to be saved as a variable so I can use it in the get_matches method.

```
class imageCapture:

    storedImges = ['C:\pythonImg\image1.jpg']

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None

    def captureImage(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            print(ret)
        else:
            ret = False
        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #this converts the colours to RGB from BGR
        self.image = img1
```

Here I save the img1 to the self.image variable so I can use it in the following method:

```
def get_Matches(self): 
        trainImg = cv2.imread(self.image,0)

        orb = cv2.ORB_create()
        kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(trainImg,None) #this finds keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
        kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(storedImges[0],None)

        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True) #create a bfMatcher object
        matches = bf.match(des1,des2) #Match descriptors
        matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance) #sorts them in order of their distance

        img3 = cv2.drawMatches(trainImg,kp1,storedImg,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2) #helps us to draw the matches.
        plt.imshow(img3)
        plt.show()
```

Then create objects and call the methods:

```
testobj = imageCapture()
testobj.captureImage()
testobj.get_Matches()
```

I know I am doing this completely wrong, I am just stuck on what sort of approach to take to get this to compile. I was thinking I would need to pass the image from **`captureImage()`** into the **`get_matches`** method via the parameter but I keep running into issues with that too. This is more due to my lack of understanding when it comes to the **`__init__`** (constructor) method and how to call and set variables.

thanks

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `self.image` is image in memory, not filename, so you can't read it from file with `imread()` - and you don't have to. Use directly `self.image` instead of `trainImg`

Answer (score 1):

In `self.image` you have image in memory, not filename, so you can't use it as filename to read image from disk with `cv2.imread(filename)`.

Use directly `self.image` instead of `trainImg` in `get_Matches()`

```
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(self.image, None)
```

---

Different is with `storedImges[0]` which is filename so you have to use `imread()` to load it

```
image = cv2.imread(storedImges[0], 0)

kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
```